# Openshift Golang force https

Tags: go, openshift

I have a Golang application using `haproxy` on `openshift`. What is the correct way to force all traffic to https?

There was a similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41428408/how-to-redirect-http-to-https-on-an-openshift-golang-app) but the answer doesn't seem to work.

I have tried to do local redirects but the I get `"too many redirects error"` consistently.

Comment: What openshift version?

Comment: You can check this doc for openshift version 2 but this product is EOL, I hope you know. https://developers.openshift.com/faq/troubleshooting.html#_how_do_i_redirect_traffic_to_https

Comment: @akostadinov , i am aware of the .htaccess  and i use it for python and it works very well. I don't however think it works in Golang. I am also not sure on how to check openshift versions or i don't see any command to do it. I am using  latest openshift-go-cart.

Comment: not an answer but v2 is EOL. Spending time deploying on it would be soon lost. Better look at https://www.openshift.com/devpreview/ . Not yet production supported but should become at some point. Not sure what deployment timeframe you're looking at. You can also run it on your hardware (where you can get official support if you wish) until public supported version becomes available.